# Which package contains Agency FB Font?

Tags: fonts

Like the title, I'm writing a brochure using Agency FB Font in LATEX but I don't know which package contains it? And how about other font such as Tahoma, Calibri,...?

Comment: There is no package for these fonts, since they are commercial fonts, distributed by the Microsoft Corporation.  If you use a Microsoft Windows operating system, chances are high that the fonts are bundled with it.  You then have to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` in conjunction with the `fontspec` package to load these system fonts into LaTeX.

Comment: This [TUGboat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84robertson.pdf) by Will Robertson gives a nice introduction to system fonts in LaTeX.

Comment: Agency FB comes with Microsoft Office (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_FB)).

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you write a simple example using Agency FB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use xelatex or lualatex to access system fonts, I used xelatex here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Agency FB}
\begin{document}
One two three.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: While this perfectly works, it is semantically awkward.  It might be better to `\setsansfont{Agency FB}` to comply with the fact that Agency FB is a Sans Serif font.

Comment: @HenriMenke perhaps. Although using Agency FB sans and latin modern roman together is probably worse, and I'm not about to to design a whole document design spec so I think I'll leave as is. Although feel free to post another answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your answer. But I'm writing in Vietnamese Language(UTF8) but it doesn't display true character. Can you help me?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Agency FB}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\begin{document}
Chế độ hoạt động
\end{document}

Comment: @Yuri sorry but the `utf8` option of the vietnam package suggests that it is designed to work with pdftex and is incompatible with xetex, you would need to ask a new question about that.